# Android: What is Source and Destination values in Porter Duff Mode

Tags: android, canvas, paint, porter-duff

I implemented a custom view. I'm drawing a bitmap using Porter Duff modes of Paint for having different effects on image in another view. My code flow is in below:

```
Layout:
<ImageView>
</ImageView>
<CustomView>
Constraint with the image view so that it lies on top in view group.
</CustomView>

Custom View:

onDraw(canvas)
{
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}
```

Now my question is, according to the [documentation of PorterDuff](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuff.Mode), it mainly blends two images. I understand the source value is the bitmap that I'm drawing but I want to know which is the destination here?
When I use **DST** mode, nothing is drawn in the custom view.
Is the image in **ImageView** destination here? But how? These are two different views. How do these views communicate each other?

Answer (score 0):

As you Already said, Views are separated and could not be blended with each others. But you could stack any number of bitmaps or drawables and draw the result on some view's canvas.

Destination is what is already drawn on canvas. You should not create additional CustomImageView inside an ImageView. Instead, extend `ImageView` class and just override the `onDraw` function.

Note that inside overrided `onDraw` you should first call `super.onDraw(canvas);` at the first line. By doing that, you first draw what image you define for the imageview (e.i. inside xml using `app:srcCompat="..."`). Now this image become your destination and you could blend it afterward.

The following code create an imageview that crop a circle in image:

First draw the the image and then DST_IN the circle.

DST_IN: Draw destination only where SRC is not transparent.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;


public class CircleImageView extends AppCompatImageView {

    Paint paint;
    public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);
        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    }


    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth()*0.5f,getHeight()*0.5f,getHeight()*0.25f,paint);
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you draw directly on canvas add this line:  `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE,null);` in the constructor of your custom view.

Comment: I'm not creating the custom view inside the image view. These two are completely separate view components. Custom View is on top of image view in view group. The custom view extends view class intentionally, not image view. 
My canvas is empty. I haven't drawn anything excepts the source bitmap. I want to know, in this case what are the destination values?
Note: I called super method on draw. I've so many other things on the custom view class. I can't write the whole class here. So, I just wrote what I think was needed to answer the question. Thanks